# Why must unicode use utf-8?

Tags: unicode, encoding

as far I know, the UNICODE is the industry standard for character mapping.

What I don't get is that why it has to be encoded via UTF-8 and not directly as Unicode?

Say the letter "a", why can't it be just stored as a String with "U+0061" as the value, and must be stored as octal 0061?

do i make any sense?

Comment: Unicode doesn't have to use UTF-8. There are other encoding schemes possible. Where did you read that UTF-8 was the only choice?

Comment: Also, it uses less memory to store as UTF-8 rather than unicode

Comment: 0061 is the *hexadecimal* representation of `'a'`, not the octal representation. Most Unicode-related documents use hexadecimal.

Comment: read [Say Hello to Unicode](http://kos.gd/say-hello-to-unicode) (shameless plug :-))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Who says it *must* be encoded as UTF-8? There are several common encodings for Unicode, including UTF-16 (big- or little-endian), and some less common ones such as [UTF-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7) and UTF-32.

Unicode itself is not an encoding; it's merely a specification of numeric code points for several thousand characters.

The Unicode code point for lowercase `a` is 0x61 in hexadecimal, 97 in decimal, or 0141 in octal.

If you're suggesting that `'a'` should be encoded as the 6-character ASCII string `"U+0061"`, that would be terribly wasteful of space and more difficult to decode than UTF-8.

If you're suggesting storing the numeric values directly, that's what UTF-32 does: it stores each character as a 32-bit (4-octet) number that directly represents the code point. The trouble with that is that it's nearly as wasteful of space as "U+0061" (4 bytes per character vs. 6.)

The UTF-8 encoding has a number of advantages. One is that it's upward compatible with ASCII. Another is that it's reasonably efficient even for non-ASCII characters, as long as most of the encoded text is within the first few thousand code points.

UTF-16 has some other advantages, but I personally prefer UTF-8. MS Windows tends to use UTF-16, but mostly for historical reasons; Windows added Unicode support when there were fewer than 65536 defined code points, which made UTF-16 equvalent to UCS-2, which is a simpler representation.

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 is only one 'memory format' of Unicode.  There is also UTF-16, UTF-32 and a number of other memory mapping formats.

UTF-8 has been used broadly because it is upwardly compatible with an 8 bit character code like Ascii.

You can tell a browser via html, mySQL at several levels, and Notepad++ vie encoding option to use other formats for the data they operate on.

DuckDuckGo or Google Unicode and you will find plenty of articles on this on the internet.  Here is one:  https://ssl.icu-project.org/docs/papers/forms_of_unicode/

Comment: thank you, the link you presented is amazingly helpful too. but i can only choose 1 answer. i give you points though.

Answer (score 1):

> Say the letter "a", why can't it be just stored as a String with "U+0061" as the value

Stored data is a sequence of byte values, generally interpreted at the lowest level as numbers. We usually use bytes that can be one of 256 values, so we look at them as numbers in the range 0 to 255.

So when you say 'just stored as a String with "U+0061"' what sequence of numbers in the range 0-255 do you mean?

Unicode code points like U+0061 are written in hexadecimal. Hexadecimal 61 is the number 97 in the more familiar decimal system, so perhaps you think that the letter 'a' should be stored as a single byte with the value 97. You might be surprised to learn that this is exactly how the encoding UTF-8 represents this string.

Of course there are more than 256 characters defined in Unicode, so not all Unicode characters can be stored as bytes with the same value as their Unicode codepoint. UTF-8 has one way of dealing with this, and there are other encodings with different ways.

UTF-32, for example, is an encoding which uses 4 bytes together at a time to represent a codepoint. Since one byte has 256 values four bytes can have 256 × 256 × 256 × 256, or 4,294,967,296 different arrangements. We can number those arrangements of bytes from 0 to 4,294,967,295 and then store every Unicode codepoint as the arrangement of bytes that we've numbered with the number corresponding to the Unicode codepoint value. This is exactly what UTF-32 does.

(However, there are different ways to assign numbers to those arrangements of four bytes and so there are multiple versions of UTF-32, such as UTF-32BE and UTF-32LE. Typically a particular medium of storing or transmitting bytes specifies its own numbering scheme, and the encoding 'UTF-32' without further qualification implies that whatever the medium's native scheme is should be used.)

Answer (score 1):

Read this article:

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 1):

> do i make any sense?

Not a lot!  (Read on ...)

> as far I know, the UNICODE (sic) is the industry standard for character mapping.

That is incorrect.  Unicode IS NOT a standard for character mapping.  It is a standard that defines a set of character codes and what they mean.

It is essentially a *catalogue* that defines a mapping of codes (Unicode "code points") to conceptual characters, but it is not a standard *for* mapping characters.  It certainly DOES NOT define a standard way to represent the code points; i.e. a mapping to a representation.  (That is what character encoding schemes do!)

> What I don't get is that why it has to be encoded via UTF-8 and not directly as Unicode?

That is incorrect.  Character data DOES NOT *have to be* encoded in UTF-8.  It *can* be encoded as UTF-8.  But it *can also* be encoded in a number of other ways too:

- The Unicode has specified a number of encoding schemes, including UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32, and various historical variants.
- There are many other standard encoding schemes (probably hundreds of them).  This Wikipedia page lists [some of the common ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings).

The various different encoding schemes have different purposes (and different limitations).  For example:

- ASCII and LATIN-1 are 7 and 8-bit character sets (respectively) that encode a *small* subset of Unicode code-points.  (ASCII encodes roman letters and numbers, some punctuation, and "control codes".  LATIN-1 adds a number of accented latin letters using in Western Europe and some other common "typographical" characters.)
- UTF-8 is a variable length encoding scheme that encodes Unicode code points as 1 to 5 bytes (octets).  (It is biased towards western usage ... since it encodes all latin / roman letters and numbers as single bytes.)
- UTF-16 is designed for encoding Unicode code points in 16-bit units.  (Java Strings are essentially UTF-16 encoded.)

> Say the letter "a", why can't it be just stored as a String with "U+0061" as the value, and must be stored as octal 0061?

In fact, a Java String is represented as a sequence of `char` values.  The `char` type is a 16-bit unsigned integer type; i.e. it has values 0 through 65535.  And the `char` value that represents a lowercase "a" character is hex 0061 == octal 141 == decimal 97.

You are incorrect about "octal 0061" ... but I can't figure out what distinction you are *actually* trying to make here, so I can't really comment on that.